# Seaborn Object Interface: custom title and facet with 2 or more variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, functional-programming, seaborn, visualization

I am using seaborn object interface and I want to go a little further in graph customization.
Here is a case with facet plot on 2 observations:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([['A','B','A','B'],['odd','odd','even','even'], [1,2,1,2], [2,4,1.5,3],]).T
    , columns= ['kind','face','Xs','Ys']
    )
(
    so.Plot(df,x='Xs' , y='Ys')
    .facet("kind","face")
    .add(so.Dot())
    .label(title= 'kind :{}'.format)
)
```

[image: facet plot on 2 observations with seaborn object interface]

As you can see, subplots title display "kind:  | kind: ".
I want to display "kind:  | face: ".

Obviously I tried `title= 'kind :{}, face :{}'.format` but it threw an error...

I discovered `.label(title= 'kind :{}'.format)` iterates over facet observation inputs and made a quick and dirty workaround.

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([['A','B','A','B'],['odd','odd','even','even'], [1,2,1,2], [2,4,1.5,3],]).T
    , columns= ['kind','face','Xs','Ys']
    )
def multiObs_facet_title(t:tuple) -> str:
    if t in ['A','B']:
        return 'kind: {}'.format(t)
    else:
        return 'face: {}'.format(t)
(
    so.Plot(df,x='Xs' , y='Ys')
    .facet("kind","face")
    .add(so.Dot())
    .label(title= multiObs_facet_title)
)
```

[image: naming according to facet observations]

I wonder if there is a better way to do this without to have checking the value of observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not what you are looking for. But with a 2-D Seaborn facet (columns and rows), it doesn't seem too bad to do it in pandas if you want to avoid defining a custom function.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([['A','B','A','B'],['odd','odd','even','even'], [1,2,1,2], [2,4,1.5,3],]).T
    , columns= ['kind','face','Xs','Ys']
    )

df["kind_1"] = "kind: "+ df["kind"]
df["face_1"] = "face: "+ df["face"]

(
    so.Plot(df,x='Xs' , y='Ys')
    .facet("kind_1","face_1")
    .add(so.Dot())
)
```

Comment: Thanks fredfeng for the answer. 
Actually, it matches my expectation.
This way is more robust and readable that using a custom function with conditional statements.

Answer (score 2):

[`Plot.label`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.label.html) supports independent `row` and `col` arguments. Also, if you pass a string into these rather than a function, they are prefixed on the respective labels. So this:

```
(
    so.Plot(df, x='Xs', y='Ys')
    .facet(col='kind', row='face')
    .add(so.Dot())
    .label(col='Kind:', row='Face:')
)
```

gives you

[image: Faceted plot with independently prefixed row and column labels]

Comment: Tiny nit: don't include a space at the end of the values for `col` and `row` in `Plot.label` as one is added automatically (perhaps seaborn should check to see whether the value already ends with whitespace before doing that...)

Comment: Is there a way to omit labeling the row or col variable? With `row=""`, it still adds labels for the row variable.
It would also be great to have the column title only once at the top (similar to `margin_titles` in `FacetGrid`) because larger grid get cluttered with so much text rapidly. But this should probably be another question.

Comment: Good catch @mwaskom; fixed. @astoeriko, funny enough, it was searching for that question that led me here. I haven't been able to figure out a way to do it, so I've opened a feature request: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3415